# Is there a way to store sensitive information like SSN in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, javascript-objects

I had asked by one of the interviewer, is there a way to store the sensitive information like SSN in Javascript? Anyone has any idea? Kindly advise.

Comment: Never store sensitive information in javascript. It's viewable and modifiable  by client side users and there isn't really a way to keep it safe.

Comment: Sensitive information shouldn't be stored client side, is that the question?

Comment: You really should encrypt the sensitive data before, e.g. using PHP.